# View LWC Locally / Install LWC dev Mobile Plugin Error

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, sfdx-plugin, sfdx-error

**Aim**: To preview LWC component locally.

**Problem** : NOT able to install `sfdx plugins:install @salesforce/lwc-dev-mobile`

**NPM Version**: 7.7.6, **NODE Version**: v15.13.0, **SFDX Version**: sfdx-cli/7.92.0-88320113e7

**Error**: Below is the error

````
    compromised = compromised || function (err) { throw err; };
                                                  ^

Error: Unable to update lock within the stale threshold
    at C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\sfdx\client\7.92.0-88320113e7\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:78645:66
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:171:23) {
  code: 'ECOMPROMISED'
}
Installing plugin @salesforce/lwc-dev-mobile... failed
    Error: yarn add @salesforce/lwc-dev-mobile@latest --non-interactive --mutex=file:C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\sfdx\yarn.lock
    --preferred-cache-folder=C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\sfdx\yarn --check-files exited with code 1```
````

Comment: are you sure you are installing the correct plugin?  local development plugin is `@salesforce/lwc-dev-server`